# Click on element if exists

Tags: uiveri5

I want to use setInterval and to try for five times to check if element exists (a button). If it exists, I want to click it and to proceed after it and, if not, I want to just proceed.

How to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Max, I am just writing the answer in a more dummy proof way:

If one needs to check if a button or something else is displayed, isDisplayed() should be called. isDisplayed() is a promise and, if the element is displayed, then in the then() resolution the continuation should be called. If the element is not displayed, the callback should be called in the catch() resolution of the promise.

Example:

```
iCheckForElementAndContinue: function(callback) {
    element.isDisplayed()
    .then({
        // Element is found
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    })
    .catch({
        // Element is not found
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way with webdriver that is the underlying API in UIVeri5. The right way is to use the browser.driver.wait() with a predicate that checks for the condition.
But such polling should  not be necessary at all with UIVeri5 when working against a UI5 application because UIVeri5 handles the waiting automatically. With the limitation that this magic works only in UI5 apps because it depends on the UI5 runtime to detect when the UI5 app is ready. So when writing tests for UI5, you don't need any pollings, you just write element(by.control()).isDisplayed() and it works fine and perfectly reliable. The check will happen at the correct time - when ui5 app is fully rendered and no polling is necessary.

Comment: I have a PlanningCalendar in which I have a Dialog as a dependent. I want to click cancel on the dialog if displayed. But the isDisplayed() of the "cancel" button is always true no matter if the dialog is rendered(shown on the screen or not). What shall I do in this case?

Comment: isDisplayed() returns a promise, not a value. So resolve the value in a .then handler.

Comment: Max, if the element is not displayed, an error is thrown, but the case is that I think that the resolution should be in the then() and the return value should just be false.